# What is the most cross-browser consistent jQuery plugin for rendering rounded corners on HTML elements without images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rounded-corners

### What is the most consistent, cross-browser compatible jQuery plugin for rendering rounded corners on HTML elements without images?

Everything I have used so far has either been inconsistent and unreliable across different browsers, and/or has added unnecessary elements that interfere with cascading CSS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wait, what?

"Every browser" except IE6/7/8 supports [`border-radius`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius): http://caniuse.com/border-radius

For the aforementioned troublesome browsers, you can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/):

> PIE currently has full or partial support for [the following CSS3 features](http://css3pie.com/about/):
>
> • border-radius
>   • box-shadow
>   • border-image
>   • multiple background images
>   • linear-gradient as background image

Comment: +1 for mentioning solution also for deprecated browsers (IE6-8)

Comment: @Tadeck: Is IE8 deprecated? By whom?

Comment: @alex: Treat it more like a opinion about Internet Explorer, browser that can still render pages as IE5 would - yes, really! Omg, just look at this: "_When there is an old DOCTYPE or when there is no DOCTYPE, IE renders it like IE5 would (quirks mode)._". And look at the chart [here](http://arstechnica.com/software/news/2008/01/ie8-super-standards-mode.ars/2).

Answer (score 2):

+1 on CSS3 PIE as well. However contrary to earlier comments, it does actually support different radii per corner, by way of multiple values on the shorthand value. See here: http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#border-radius

As an example: `border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;` will round the top corners but leave the bottom corners square. You can also supply different radii for x vs. y for each corner, for example: `border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0 / 10px 10px 0 0;`

Since all other current versions of the major browsers support this same exact shorthand, it is easy in combination with PIE to get them all looking alike as long as you use the shorthand.

Comment: +1, amazing. I clearly need to read the documentation more carefully, because I literally had no idea that worked. I've never needed it myself, but I have told other people that it doesn't work. Oops..